# Appending to $('body') reloads images

Tags: jquery, append, document-body

The webpage has some images. After loading the document the images are fully loaded. Some seconds later they disappear and then they come back. I've tracked down the problem to this line.

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div name="abc">some blah</div>'
    + document.body.innerHTML;
```

, changed it into:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div name="abc">some blah</div>';
```

Hasn't helped, changed it into:

```
$("body").append('<div name="abc">some blah</div>');
```

No success at all.

It seems to me that the complete html code of the body is replaced by a new on. That's why it is empty for a short time. The browser removes all elements and repaints them.

Any solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Cntrl + F any of these words. - `show`, `hide`, `display`, `none`, `visibility`, `opacity`

Comment: How and where exactly(!) do you call the .append() method and which browser are you using for testing? I set up a small example on jsbin.com and it didn't show this behavior. Which version of jQuery?

Comment: Setting the html (using innerHTML) *will* do what you've described because you're not just adding to the page - you're setting it's value to what it currently is, plus something else.  That's a reload.  jQuery append does not do that.  Press F12 and execute `$("body").append("<div style=\"position:absolute;left:0;top:0;padding:10px;background-color:#ffffff\">This div was appended</div>");` - it will not reload this page.

Comment: Problem found and will be elimenated. There was an innerHtml = '...' completely somewhere else. Very wierd that they both were executed simultaneously while debugging. Thanks for your great input anyway :)